# Issue running Node NPM

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

I already have idea about Angular 1.x. I'm planning to learn Angular 2.x. By this [Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), they are asking to install node.js and npm. I installed node.js. From where to write the command "npm install"? from the node.js installation directory or from my project directory? When i write from project directory, it says "npm is not an internal/external command" I got stuck here.

Any help??

Comment: What happens if you type node --version? Node should be installed globally so you should be able to run node and/or npm commands from any directory.
What OS are you running?

Comment: @0991 open node command prompt check there if install or not

Comment: I'm using Windows 10..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install latest version of node (6.2.2), try using linux console such as git bash .
got to the folder where you want to install angular .

create folder structue using the tutorial available here 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

explained very neatly and straight to the point , all the best!

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But i got stuck in building the basic stuff itself..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAPQF_GA7Qg check this youtube video it clearly explains the installation and creation of an app in the ng-2

Answer (score 1):

First install `Node` with respective OS 
then in cmd prompt type `node`, if all the installation process fine then `REPL` will executed 
then 
install packages by 
typing

```
npm install <package name>
```